# Disable back button navigation action

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, navigation

I have one `home screen` and `detail screen`. From `home screen` I use `push` navigation and mov to `detail screen`.

In my `detail screen` I have one back button to go back to `home screen`. Because I did `push` from `home screen`. This scenario is working fine.

But when user tap on back button I don't want to move the screen back to my home screen if some condition matched. Lets say I have one button called value score. If score count is 0. Then I don't want user to go back. If its more than 1 then if user clicks on back button they can move to home screen.

So I did :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        if count > 0 {
           // Dont move , just stay in same screen
        } else {
           // Move to back home screen
        }
    }
}
```

When trying this, I am still able to go back to home screen on click of back button. How can I stay in same screen?

Comment: There is not enough code. Based on what you have, it should work, but it doesn't, so we'd need to see more

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a custom back button in navigation controller.

```
func setupCustomBackBtn() {
    
    let navBackBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
    navBackBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    navBackBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "customBack"), for: .normal)
    
    navBackBtn.frame = CGRect(x: -20, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32)
    let customBackBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navBackBtn)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackBarBtn
    
}


@objc func backBtnAction() {
}
```

Comment: i need to do with my nav bar back button. Not with my custom button. That is the requirement, Is it possible ?

Comment: i do not know any other method but my hack works 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

You should create back button action function and use your code:

```
if self.isMovingFromParent {
    if count > 0 {
       // Dont move , just stay in same screen
    } else {
       // Move to back home screen
    }
}
```

in that function.

```
@IBAction func tapOnBackButton() {
    if count == 0 {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add identifier to the pop Segue

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if let ident = identifier {
        if ident == "YourIdentifier" {
            if count > 0 {
                // Dont move , just stay in same screen
                return false
            }
            else {
                // Move to back home screen
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```